# Unreal Engine Pixel Streaming

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-chrome, firefox, browser, unreal-engine5

I have set up a pixel streaming in UE5 in AWS(Amazon Web Services) it works perfectly on my laptop, mobile and my colleagues system (same WiFi).

When I send that public IP4 link to my client in another city it just appears blank, after clicking the triangle (play button) in Pixel Streaming.

Edit 1: when I change the location(IP) using VPN, it also not working on my laptop too.

EDIT 2:

I'm using UE5 pixelStreaming, It works on many devices/locations, but it didn't work on some locations. I contacted AWS the checked different locations and its working on their side.

surprisingly i didn't do anything it worked on all devices in all locations the next day.

On the next day this problem arise again it didn't work in my client's whole office.

after a few hours, it started to work on some of my client devices(mobile /web browser).

I checked the remote desktop I find out that webRTC data is not coming there.

Why WebRTC data not coming in some of the devices?

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be because you didn't allow access from other networks on AWS, so it only allows those on your network to see it. While not this exact issue, something similar happened to me before.

Comment: How to allow access from another network on AWS.